# Fluent nhibernate one to one mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How do I make a one to one mapping.

```cs
public class Setting
{
    public virtual Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateFilters TaskFilterOption { get; set; }
    public virtual string TimeZoneId { get; set; }
    public virtual string TimeZoneName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndOfTerm { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Setting Class map:

```cs
public SettingMap() 
{
    // Id(Reveal.Member<Setting>("StudentId")).GeneratedBy.Foreign("StudentId");
     
    //Id(x => x.StudentId);
       
    Map(x => x.TaskFilterOption)
        .Default(DateFilters.All.ToString())
        .NvarcharWithMaxSize()
        .Not.Nullable();
        
    Map(x => x.TimeZoneId)
        .NvarcharWithMaxSize()
        .Not.Nullable();
        
    Map(x => x.TimeZoneName)
        .NvarcharWithMaxSize()
        .Not.Nullable();
        
    Map(x => x.EndOfTerm)
        .Default("5/21/2011")
        .Not.Nullable();
       
    HasOne(x => x.Student);
}
```

---

Student Class map

```cs
public class StudentMap: ClassMap<Student> 
{
    public StudentMap() 
    {
        Id(x => x.StudentId);
        
        HasOne(x => x.Setting)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public virtual Guid StudentId { get; private set; }
    public virtual Setting Setting { get; set; }
}
```

---

Now every time I try to create a settings object and save it to the database it crashes.

```cs
Setting setting = new Setting 
{
    TimeZoneId = viewModel.SelectedTimeZone,
    TimeZoneName = info.DisplayName,
    EndOfTerm = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
    Student = student
};
```

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Settings_Students". The conflict occurred in database "Database", table "dbo.Students", column 'StudentId'.
> The statement has been terminated.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Settings_Students". The conflict occurred in database "Database", table "dbo.Students", column 'StudentId'.
> The statement has been terminated.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

```cs
public class StudentMap: ClassMap<Student> 
{
    public StudentMap() 
    {
        Id(x => x.StudentId)
            .GeneratedBy.Guid();
        
        HasOne(x => x.Setting)
            .PropertyRef("Student")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class SettingMap: ClassMap<Setting> 
{
    public SettingMap() 
    {
        Id(x => x.StudentId)
            .GeneratedBy.Guid();
            
        Map(x => x.TaskFilterOption)
            .Default(DateFilters.All.ToString())
            .NvarcharWithMaxSize().Not.Nullable();
        
        Map(x => x.TimeZoneId)
            .NvarcharWithMaxSize().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TimeZoneName)
            .NvarcharWithMaxSize().Not.Nullable();
            
        Map(x => x.EndOfTerm)
            .Default("5/21/2011").Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Student).Unique();
    }
}
```

---

```cs
Setting setting = new Setting 
{
    TimeZoneId = viewModel.SelectedTimeZone,
    TimeZoneName = info.DisplayName,
    EndOfTerm = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
    Student = student
};

studentRepo.SaveSettings(setting);
studentRepo.Commit();
```

I get these error for both ways

> Invalid index 5 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=5. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Invalid index 5 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=5. Source Error: Line 76:             using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction()) Line 77:   { Line 78:                 transaction.Commit(); Line 79:         } Line 80:         }

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are two basic ways how to map bidirectional one-to-one association in NH. Let's say the classes look like this:

```
public class Setting
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Setting Setting { get; set; }
}
```

Setting class is a master in the association ("aggregate root"). It is quite unusual but it depends on problem domain...

**Primary key association**

```
public SettingMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
    HasOne(x => x.Student).Cascade.All();
}

public StudentMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Setting");
    HasOne(x => x.Setting).Constrained();
}
```

and a new setting instance should be stored:

```
        var setting = new Setting();

        setting.Student = new Student();
        setting.Student.Name = "student1";
        setting.Student.Setting = setting;
        setting.Name = "setting1";

        session.Save(setting);
```

**Foreign key association**

```
public SettingMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
    References(x => x.Student).Unique().Cascade.All();
}

public StudentMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
    HasOne(x => x.Setting).Cascade.All().PropertyRef("Student");
}
```

Primary key association is close to your solution. Primary key association should be used only when you are absolutely sure that the association will be always one-to-one. Note that AllDeleteOrphan cascade is not supported for one-to-one in NH.

EDIT: For more details see:

http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/03/conform-mapping-one-to-one.html

http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one

Comment: Hmm, it's weird. I have never seen such exception. Does it have any inner exception? Do you use any listeners or interceptor?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that there are two properties mapped to one column in Setting class: Student reference and StudentId property. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388914/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one-or-one-to-zero/785163#785163.

Comment: I just created an example project where "Table A" has a primary key, and "Table B" has a primary key that's also a foreign key to "Table A." The **Foreign Key Association** worked great in this case. The important thing to remember is your "Table B" mapping needs to map the primary key value AND the HasOne association separately.

Comment: PropertyRef what it means ?

Answer (score 4):

Here a complete sample with foreign key association

```
using System;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace NhOneToOne
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                                             .Database(
                                                    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                                                                      .ConnectionString(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=NHTest;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False")
                                                                      .ShowSql()
                                              )
                                             .Mappings(m => m
                                             .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
                                             .BuildSessionFactory();

                ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();


                Parent parent = new Parent();
                parent.Name = "test";
                Child child = new Child();
                child.Parent = parent;
                parent.Child = child;
                session.Save(parent);
                session.Save(child);

                int id = parent.Id;
                session.Clear();
                parent = session.Get<Parent>(id);
                child = parent.Child;


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
            }
        }

    }

    public class Child
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Child Child { get; set; }

    }

    public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
    {
        public ChildMap()
        {
            Table("ChildTable");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
            Map(x => x.Name);

            References(x => x.Parent).Column("IdParent");

        }
    }

    public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
    {
        public ParentMap()
        {
            Table("ParentTable");
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
            Map(x => x.Name);

            HasOne(x => x.Child).PropertyRef(nameof(Child.Parent));
        }

    }
}
```

And the SQL to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParentTable] (
    [Id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChildTable] (
    [Id]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IdParent] INT          NOT NULL,
    [Name]     VARCHAR (50) NULL
);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChildTable]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ChildTable_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([IdParent]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ParentTable] ([Id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define one of the sides of the relationship as Inverse(), otherwise there is a redundant column in the database and this may cause the problem.

If this doesn't work, output the SQL statements generated by NHibernate (using ShowSql or through log4net) and try to understand why the foreign key constraint is violated (or post it here with the SQL, and don't forget the values of the bind variables that appear afer the SQL statement).

Answer (score 0):

You should not define the StudentId in Sesstings class. Sessting class already has it (from 
`public virtual Student Student { get; set; }` ). Probably it should be SesstingId and you should map the Id field as well (you have to define/map the primary key).

Comment: If I remove StudentId from Settings fluent nhibernate will crash and as for a PK