# Mapping by code Zero-Or-One relationship

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following database structure, which **I cannot change**:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE UserAvatars (
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    Width INT NOT NULL,
    Height INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES Users(ID),
)
```

Basically, a User can have **Zero-or-one** avatars (I removed columns to simplify the example).

```
class User
{
    public int ID { get; protected set; }

    public UserAvatar Avatar { get; set; }
}

class UserAvatar
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following mapping:

```
class UserMapping : ClassMapping<User>
{
    public UserMapping() 
    {
        Id(x => x.ID, m => {
            m.Generator(Generators.Identity);
        });

        OneToOne(x => x.Avatar);
    }
}

class UserAvatarMapping : ClassMapping<UserAvatar>
{
    public UserAvatar() 
    {
        Id(x => x.User, m =>
        {
            m.Generator(Generators.Foreign<User>(u => u.ID));
        });

        Property(x => x.Width);
        Property(x => x.Height);
    }
}
```

However, when trying run my app, I get an `NHibernate.MappingException`:

> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document:
>   mapping_by_code----> NHibernate.MappingException : Could not determine
>   type for: MyApp.Models.UserAvatar, MyApp, for columns:
>   NHibernate.Mapping.Column(User)

I can't make any sense of this cryptic error.

How do I accomplish the mapping where a `User` could have zero or one Avatars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID is important almost for every entity mapped by NHibernate (ORM). So, we should extend the Avatar class:

```
class UserAvatar
{
    // every(stuff) should have its ID
    public int ID { get; protected set; } 
    public User User { get; set; }
    ...
```

The ID value will be managed by one-to-one relationship. So, now let's adjust the mapping.

```
public UserAvatar() 
{
    Id(x => x.ID);

    HasOne(x => x.User)
      .Constrained()
      .ForeignKey();
    ...

public UserMapping() 
{
    Id(x => x.ID);
    HasOne(s => s.Avatar).Cascade.All();
```

Related and really interesting reading:

- [How to do a fluent nhibernate one to one mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085568/)
- [Fluent NHibernate & HasOne(): how to implement a one-to-one relationship](http://brunoreis.com/tech/fluent-nhibernate-hasone-how-implement-one-to-one-relationship/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try this tomorrow when I get to work.  Do you have any reference for mapping-by-code (not fluent nhibernate)?  No worries if you don't.

Comment: Yes, there are stories how to use the mapping by code. One-to-one is here: http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetoone.html, the *index* of them is here: http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html

Comment: Thanks @Radim, this helped greatly in solving the problem.  I'm going to post my solution which uses mapping-by-code.

Comment: Great to see that. Enjoy NHibernate, amazing tool

Answer (score 4):

Taking from Radim Köhler's guidence, the final classes / mapping that solved the problem:

```
class User
{
    public int ID { get; protected set; }
    public UserAvatar Avatar { get; set; }
}

class UserAvatar
{
    public int UserID { get; protected set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

With the following mapping:

```
class UserMapping : ClassMapping<User>
{
    public UserMapping() 
    {
        Id(x => x.ID, m => {
            m.Generator(Generators.Identity);
        });

        OneToOne(x => x.Avatar, m =>
        {
            m.Cascade(Cascade.All);
            m.Constrained(false);
        });         
    }
}

class UserAvatarMapping : ClassMapping<UserAvatar>
{
    public UserAvatar() 
    {
        Id(x => x.UserID, m =>
        {
            m.Generator(Generators.Foreign<UserAvatar>(u => u.User));
        });

        OneToOne(x => x.User, m =>
        {
            m.Constrained(true);
        });         

        Property(x => x.Width);
        Property(x => x.Height);
    }
}
```