# one to one mapping in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

I am using nhibernate. My code is as below

```
public class Store
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }

        public Store()
        {
            Staff = new List<Employee>();
        }
    }
```

Employee class

```
    public class Employee
        {
            public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
            public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
            public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
            public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
        }
```

storemap

```
    public class StoreMap:ClassMap<Store>
        {
            public StoreMap() 
            {
                Id(x => x.Id);
                Map(x => x.Name);
                HasMany(x => x.Staff).WithKeyColumn("store");
              }
        }
```

employeemap

```
public EmployeeMap ()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.FirstName);
            Map(x => x.LastName);
            References(x => x.Store  ).WithColumns("store");
        }
```

this is working fine. but i want one to one relation between employee and store and for that i try this but this doesn't work.
in employeemap
    References(x => x.Store).WithForeignKey("store");
and in stormap

```
HasOne(x => x.Staff).WithForeignKey("store");
```

but this result in following error

persistent class not known:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[test.Models.Employee, test,
 Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

The `one-to-one` mapping is very specific. It says, that one object cannat exist without the other. Check docs [5.1.11. one-to-one](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) and this for fluent [How to do a fluent nhibernate one to one mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085568/).

We can make it as an example liek this:

```
public StoreMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    HasOne(x => x.Staff).Cascade.All();
}

public EmployeeMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Store");
    HasOne(x => x.Store).Constrained();
}
```

Where is the Problem? Now we would have the `Store` which can live alone. That's ok. But any `Employee` will require a `Store` to be assigned to. And what is more important... the `Employee` won't have its own ID column. It will be in fact the column which could be nameed "StoreId", because the ID value would come from the Store.ID

#### suggestion

This scenario is very rare. And in fact, the mapping you already have seems to me pretty good.

I guess that you are trying to limit the amount of `Staff` assigned to the `Store`. This could be reasonable, and we can achieve that on the Buisness layer.

A clear (simplified) example could be something like this:

```
public class Store
{
    ...
    // not public
    protected virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }
    // here we do the trick on top of the mapping/hidden persistence layer
    public virtual Employee Employee 
    { 
       get { return Staff.FirstOrDefault(); }
       set { Staff[0] = value ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A list `virtual IList<Employee> Staff` cannot map to HasOne

Simply make it not to be a list should work ;)