# What's the proper design for a one-to-one relationship using Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table of Recipes.  Each Recipe has one and only one row in table RecipeMetadata, which contains various data about the recipe that I don't want to store in the `Recipes` table for various reasons.  Thus, `Recipes` and `RecipeMetadata` have a one-to-one mapping.  My `Recipes` table is as follows:

```
public partial class RecipesMap : ClassMap<Recipes>
{
   public RecipesMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.RecipeId);

      // Map() various columns here

      HasMany(x => x.Ingredients).KeyColumn("RecipeId");
      HasOne(x => x.Metadata);
   }
}
```

And here's my `RecipeMetadata` table:

```
public partial class RecipeMetadataMap : ClassMap<RecipeMetadata>
{
   public RecipeMetadataMap()
   {
      Id(x => x.RecipeMetadataId);

      // Map() various columns here

      References<Recipes>(x => x.Recipe).Column("RecipeId").Not.Nullable();
   }
}
```

However, when I load a `Recipe` and access the `Metadata` property, it attempts to find a row in `RecipeMetadata` where `Recipes.RecipeId = RecipeMetadata.RecipeMetadataId`.  In other words, it does the join using the primary keys on both tables.

With my table schema, `RecipeMetadataId` is a key unique only to that table, and has nothing to do with `RecipeId`.  `RecipeMetadata` has another column, also called `RecipeId` which has a foreign key constraint on `Recipes.  The JOIN should work as:

```
Recipes.RecipeId = RecipeMetadata.RecipeId
```

**My Questions:**

1. Am I wrong for wanting `RecipeMetadata` to have its own unique ID, and to use a separate column to link this to `Recipes`?  Obviously, I have a FK constraint as well as a unique index on `RecipeMetadata.RecipeId` so there's no perf impact.  Yes, there's some extra bytes on the disk for storing an arguably unnecessary ID on this table.
2. I've never seen a table whose *primary key* also  has a foreign key constraint on another table.  Is this legit practice?  It seems to be the way nHibernate *prefers* to behave by default.  Should I give in and let it have its way?
3. Provided I don't want to change the database (Though I can be convinced to do so if given a legitimate reason), how can I create the desired one-to-one mapping with this model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate has a strict definition of one-to-one relationships. Strict but fair. In NHibernate one-to-one relationship means that the a row in table A always has a matching row in table B.

1. Right or wrong, that won't work with NHibernate's one-to-one mapping. Note that the model you propose is identical to how a one-to-many relationship would be modeled.
2. It's legit and enforces the one-to-one relationship.
3. Since you want the recipe to always have an associated metadata row, I would model it using NHibernate's one-to-one mapping. Alternatively, you can map it as one-to-many but only expose one instance as a property.

See also: [Ayende's post on the topic](http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one).

Comment: So, you're saying NHibernate defines a one-to-one relationship as two tables that share a *primary key*?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I should have stated it that way. I should have mentioned another alternative, mapping it as many-to-one (references) from the recipe side. That should work since it's unlikely you'll navigate or query from metadata to recipe.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense.  I prefer to do things the way NHibernate recommends, as it causes less problems down the road.  It was a bit of a hassle to change the schema around (I had some views I had to rework) but everything is working great now.

Comment: Small note: With NHibernate has `one-to-one` a *side-effect* : any select of the Reciepe - will JOIN the data from both tables. Always. That's how NHibernate works. `one-to-many` is harder to apply *here*, but at the end, it would be more flexible. A simplified how to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20788642/1679310. Anyhow, nice Q and A

Comment: @RadimKöhler - Thanks.  Looks like I might be better off with one-to-many, if perf becomes critical..  I'll make a note of this in the code.