# Fluent Nhibernate One-to-one lazy loading when invoking a method

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading, one-to-one

Here are my classes and mapping overrides, when I call the IsActive method on Member, for some reason nhibernate fetches the MemberExtraFields from the database. This is causing n+1 issues when I call a method on a list.

Is there anything that I could to fix this, I have all laziness (NoProxy, Proxy, False)

```
public class Member
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual MemberExtraFields MemberExtraFields { get; set; }


    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsActive()
    {
        return Enabled;
    }

}

public class MemberExtraFields
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual bool ExcludeFromCompetitions { get; set; }

    public virtual Member Member { get; protected set; }
}

public class MemberMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Member>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Member> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        mapping.HasOne(x => x.MemberExtraFields)
                        .Cascade.All().LazyLoad(Laziness.NoProxy);
    }
}

public class MemberExtraFieldsMap : IAutoMappingOverride<MemberExtraFields>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<MemberExtraFields> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Member");
        mapping.HasOne(x => x.Member).Constrained().ForeignKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried `References()` instead of `.HasOne()`? If i remember right, `.HasOne()` references are always loaded.

Comment: @Rabban changing it to Reference worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `References` instead of `HasOne`. `HasOne` is tight coupling.

Note that your `IsActive()` method returns `Enabled` property which is associated to your database field and needs to be loaded from there. When `NHibernate` executes the query to fill that property, it also executes another query to fill `MemberExtraFields MemberExtraFields { get; set; }` property.

Refer accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085568/how-to-do-a-fluent-nhibernate-one-to-one-mapping).

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked. I had to do tweak the accepted answer to get it working.

I had to change to reference on both ends because on database side MemberExtraFields table primary key and foreign key are the same, so when I tried to add a member, nhibernate was trying to add the memberextrafield first before adding member and this was causing "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" issue. To overcome this I had update the mappings to not save MemberExtraFields part of member.